# Calling User Input in Color Selection - Python Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am not too sure if I am even phrasing the question correctly - the code I have thus far is below:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

colors = {'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black'}

def drawSquare(t,x,y,size,fill_color):

    t.penup() # Pickup turtle
    t.goto(x,y) # Move Turtle
    t.pendown() # Drop turtle
    t.fillcolor(fill_color)
    t.begin_fill()  # Shape Fill begin
    for square in range(0,4):
        t.forward(size) # move forward
        t.right(90) # turn 90 degrees
    t.end_fill() # Shape Fill End

def drawBoard():

    square_color = turtle.textinput("Color Selection", "Enter a color:") # Set color to be user defined
    pos_x = turtle.numinput("Position Selection", "Enter a Position for X") # Set position x to be user defined
    pos_y = turtle.numinput("Position Selection", "Enter a Position for Y") # Set position y to be user defined
    box_size = turtle.numinput("Box Size Selection", "Enter a Box Size (1-50)") # Set box size to be user defined
    for squareOne in range(0,8): # Create a chess board dimension
        for squareTwo in range(0,8): 
            drawSquare(t,pos_x+squareTwo*box_size,pos_y+squareOne*box_size,box_size,square_color)
            square_color = 'Black' if square_color == 'white' else 'white' 
        square_color = 'Black' if square_color == 'white' else 'white' 

drawBoard() # Call drawBoard Function

turtle.done()
```

Things fall apart around the square_color = 'Black' line in the drawBoard function. My goal is to dictate the color of the squares based on the user input assigned to variable "square_color". Unfortunately, I am really not too sure how to do this - or if this would even be the most efficient way of doing so.

If the user chooses a color, only the first square is that color, and the rest of the board is followed by what is coded in. Not sure how to name this problem, otherwise I would be happy to go hunting myself.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to alternate between the input color and another color? If I choose red, should it alternate between red and black?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
t = turtle.Turtle()

colors = {'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black'}

def drawSquare(t,x,y,size,fill_color):

    t.penup() # Pickup turtle
    t.goto(x,y) # Move Turtle
    t.pendown() # Drop turtle
    t.fillcolor(fill_color)
    t.begin_fill()  # Shape Fill begin
    for square in range(0,4):
        t.forward(size) # move forward
        t.right(90) # turn 90 degrees
    t.end_fill() # Shape Fill End

def drawBoard():

    square_color = turtle.textinput("Color Selection", "Enter a color:") # Set color to be user defined
    square_color = 'white' if square_color == 'black' else square_color # Changed here
    pos_x = turtle.numinput("Position Selection", "Enter a Position for X") # Set position x to be user defined
    pos_y = turtle.numinput("Position Selection", "Enter a Position for Y") # Set position y to be user defined
    box_size = turtle.numinput("Box Size Selection", "Enter a Box Size (1-50)") # Set box size to be user defined
    for squareOne in range(0,8): # Create a chess board dimension
        for squareTwo in range(0,8):
            drawSquare(t,pos_x+squareTwo*box_size,pos_y+squareOne*box_size,box_size,square_color if (squareTwo+squareOne)%2 == 0 else 'black') # Changed Here

drawBoard() # Call drawBoard Function

turtle.done()
```

So, I have only changed two lines:
I have moved `square_color = 'white' if square_color == 'black' else square_color` to earlier on in youn code so that if the user inputs white, then it changes the color to be black so that you can have different colors rather than one large mass.

I have also changed where you call your `drawSquare()` function so that when you call it, it will then decide whether to add a black square, or one of the color you chose. I am doing this by using a modulo to see whether the combination of both `squareOne` and `squareTwo` is even, and then using that to change the color.

Comment: That is it! I worked for hours and this never occurred to me - definitely saving this one for future reference. Thank you again!